# Having problems splitting up UIImageView into smaller images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I'm trying to take a `UIImageView`, resize that image and display it. Then i want to break up that image into smaller pieces and display them.

The resized image displays correctly but it appears that the "split up" images are too big; i'm thinking they are coming from the original (slightly bigger) image. The following screenshot shows the resized image on the left and the a column of split up images from the left hand side.

[image]

The fact that the resized image is displaying correctly and the smaller ones aren't has me confused. Any ideas would be appreciated - or even an alternative. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    width = imgOriginal.frame.size.width;
    height = imgOriginal.frame.size.height;
    whratio = width/height; 
    [self getOriginalImageInfo];
    [self resizeImage];
    resizedImage = [self resizeImage];
}

-(void) getOriginalImageInfo {
    lblWidth.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", width];
    lblHeight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", height];
    lblWHRatio.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", whratio];
}


-(UIImageView*) resizeImage {
    if (whratio >= 0.7 && whratio <=0.89) {
        imgOriginal.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 500, 600);
        imgOriginal.autoresizingMask = NO;
        float resizedWHRatio = (imgOriginal.frame.size.width)/(imgOriginal.frame.size.height);
        lblResizedWidth.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", imgOriginal.frame.size.width];
        lblResizedHeight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", imgOriginal.frame.size.height];
        lblResizedWHRatio.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", resizedWHRatio];
        return imgOriginal;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (IBAction)easyPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Easy button pressed");
    CGImageRef original = [resizedImage.image CGImage];
    float pieceWidth = (resizedImage.frame.size.width) / 5;
    float pieceHeight = (resizedImage.frame.size.height) / 6;
    for (int i =0; i<6; i++) {
        CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0+((float)i*pieceHeight), pieceWidth, pieceHeight);
        CGImageRef newTile =  CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(original, rectangle);
        UIImageView *puzzlePiece = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(611, 20+((float)i*pieceHeight), pieceWidth, pieceHeight)];
        puzzlePiece.tag = i+1;
        puzzlePiece.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newTile];
        puzzlePiece.alpha = 0.5;
        [puzzlePiece.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
        [puzzlePiece.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
        [self.view addSubview:puzzlePiece];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the same scaling factor to the partial images as you are to the main image!!!

OR

Take the screenshot of the UIImageView being displayed and split that up instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i'm doing your second option by using `resizedImage` as the base image for splitting.

Comment: UIImageView does not resize the base image, it will scale / resize a copy for display, but keeps the original buffered.  So when you go and get the UIImageView.image, it is going to return to you the original.  Thus you are splitting up the bigger (not for display) version of the image.